# Javascript Validation for Contact Form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to create a validation form for a contact page.  However, everytime I click on my submit or clear buttons, it seems to be reloading the page.  I cannot figure it out, though I'm sure it's something right in front of me.

Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/ahaxos/1/edit

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all these lines inside your validation function because they do not read any current values from your form when they are in the global scope (outside of all functions):

```
var handletxt = form.handle.value;
var emailtxt = form.email.value;
var pcbox = form.pc.checked;
var ps3box = form.ps3.checked;
var wiibox = form.wiiU.checked;
var xboxbox = form.xbox.checked;
var actionbox = form.action.checked;
var fpsbox = form.fps.checked;
var puzzlebox = form.puzzle.checked;
var rtsbox = form.rts.checked;
var mobabox = form.moba.checked;
var rpgbox = form.rpg.checked;
var suggesttxt = form.suggest.value;
var error=[];
```

Also, the variable "form" is undefined. You need to use the same variable name "form" within the validation function that you use elsewhere, or else rewrite your statements to use the variable ContactForm within the validater function:

```
/* change this line */
function validater(ContactForm){

/* change to this so that your variable names match up */
function validater(form){
```

Answer (score -1):

> SCRIPT5009: 'form' is undefined

You appear to be trying to set variables depending on the form element, before the form exists on the page. Also, you're not returning anything from `validater`.

That being said, you should no longer be using JavaScript to validate forms. Instead prefer HTML5 form validation. In your case, add the `required` attribute to required fields, and use `input type="email"` for the email input.

Comment: some browsers does not support html5 and this is a question

Comment: The only people who have browsers that do not support HTML5 are those who deliberately choose to ignore Windows Update's attempts to upgrade their browser, or people in China with pirated versions of Windows.

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't even matter because client-side validation should never be trusted and always backed up with server-side validation before processing. So it really doesn't matter if the browser doesn't support the latest HTML.

Comment: I'm doing this for a class, and this is the requirement for it.

Comment: @Kolink kidding? so u r talking about good approach. if we need to minimize reqests?